# Display additional values in holoviews sankey labels or hover information

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh, holoviews

I would like to find a way to modify the labels on holoviews sankey diagrams that they show, in addition to the numerical values, also the percentage values.

For example:

```
import holoviews as hv
import pandas as pd
hv.extension('bokeh')


data = {'A':['XX','XY','YY','XY','XX','XX'],
        'B':['RR','KK','KK','RR','RK','KK'],
        'values':[10,5,8,15,19,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A','B','values'])
    
sankey = hv.Sankey(df)
```

For 'From' label 'YY' which is 'YY - 8' change this to 'YY - 8 (13.7%)' - add the additional percentage in there.

I have found ways to change from the absolute value to percentage by using something along the lines of:

```
value_dim = hv.Dimension('Percentage', unit='%')
```

But can't find a way to have both values in the label.

Additionally, I tried to modify the hover tag. In my search to find ways to modify this I found ways to reference and display various attributes in the hover information (through the bokeh tooltips) but it does not seem like you can manipulate this information.

Answer (score 3):

In this post two possible ways are explained how to achive the wanted result. Let's start with the example DataFrame and the necessary imports.

```
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts, dim # only needed for 2. solution
import pandas as pd

data = {'A':['XX','XY','YY','XY','XX','XX'],
        'B':['RR','KK','KK','RR','RK','KK'],
        'values':[10,5,8,15,19,1],
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**1. Option**
Use `hv.Dimension(spec, **params)`, which gives you the opportunity to apply a formatter with the keyword `value_format` to a column name. This formatter is simple the combination of the value and the value in percent.

```
total = df.groupby('A', sort=False)['values'].sum().sum()

def fmt(x):
    return f'{x} ({round(x/total,2)}%)'

hv.Sankey(df, vdims = hv.Dimension('values', value_format=fmt))
```

**2. Option**
Extend the DataFrame `df` by one column wich stores the labels, you want to use. This can be later reused inside the Sankey, with `opts(labels=dim('labels'))`. To ckeck if the calculations are correct, you can turn `show_values` on, but this will cause a duplicate inside the labels. Therefor in the final solution `show_values` is set to `False`. This can be sometime tricky to find the correct order.

```
labels = []
for item in ['A', 'B']:
    grouper = df.groupby(item, sort=False)['values']
    total_sum = grouper.sum().sum()
    for name, group in grouper:
        _sum = group.sum()
        _percent = round(_sum/total_sum,2)
        labels.append(f'{name} - {_sum} ({_percent}%)')
df['labels'] = labels

hv.Sankey(df).opts(show_values=False, labels=dim('labels'))
```

The downside of this solution is, that we apply a `groupby` for both columns `'A'` and `'B'`. This is something `holoviews` will do, too. So this is not very efficient.

**Output**

[image: Sanky with new Labels]

**Comment**

Both solutions create nearly the same figure, except that the HoverTool is not equal.

Comment: Great tip - I used   _def fmt(x):   return f'\n{x}'_ to split labels and values into two rows

Comment: @mosc9575 This might be a question for another thread, but can you control the values shown when hovering? The reason I'm asking, is because I want to use the log10 values as the flow widths, but I want the real value to be shown when hovering.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen I know that Bokeh offers a `CustomJSHover` which is made to modify the prints in a Hovertool. Right now I don't know how to use it but you are welcome to open a new question.

Comment: I found a solution here: https://discourse.holoviz.org/t/how-to-create-a-conditional-custom-hover-tool-for-a-holoviews-plot/311 It makes use of `HoverTool` and `CustomJSHover` of `bokeh.models`. I create a column with log10 values `df['flow_log10'] = np.log10(df['flow'])` and then I do power of ten in the formatter `'@flow_log10': CustomJSHover(code='''var value; return Math.round(10 ** value)'''),`.